# A question on use of square integrable functions

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, quantum-mechanics

I'm approaching this from a physicist's perspective, so apologies for any inaccuracies (and lack of rigour).

As far as I understand it, a *square-integrable* function $f(x)$ satisfies the condition $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\big\vert f(x)\big\vert^{2}\;dx\;<\;\infty$$ Often in physics textbooks, especially in quantum mechanics (QM), the author states that this implies that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}f(x)=0$$ However, I have come to understand that this statement is not necessarily true. This being the case, how does one argue, for example, that $$\mathscr{F}[f'](x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f'(x)e^{-ikx}\;dx=(ik)\mathscr{F}[f](x)$$ as doesn't this rely on the fact that $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$, such that the boundary term (introduced through integration-by-parts) $$f(x)e^{-ikx}\big\vert_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$ equals zero?

[The fact that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}f(x)=0$ (such that the boundary term vanishes) is also used in QM to argue that the derivative operator is *anti-Hermitian*]

Comment: square integrable means $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f|^2 < \infty$!

Comment: The integral formula that you provide for the Fourier transform isn't universally valid.

Comment: @user251257   Sorry, I've edited to correct.

Comment: @UmbertoP.   When is it not valid? This is the only form that I've ever been taught about.

Comment: Another approach than to argue that the boundary terms vanish is to argue by density. The space for which you (probably) want to prove claims as $\mathcal{f'} = i\xi \mathcal{F}f(\xi)$ is the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}(\Bbb{R})$ (arbitrary square integrable functions are not differentiable). Here, $C_c^\infty$ is a dense subspace. For such functions, the derivation is easy. Then you use that every $f \in W^{1,2}$ can be approximated by $f_n \in C_c^\infty$ and use things like the Plancherel theorem (so that you get e.g. $\mathcal{F}f_n \to \mathcal{F}f$ to conclude the proof.

Answer (score 4):

If $f$ and $f'$ are in $L^{2}$, then $ff'$ is absolutely integrable because
$$
         2|ff'| \le |f|^{2}+|f'|^{2}.
$$
Therefore, in this case, the following has finite limits as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$:
$$
            f^{2}(x)-f^{2}(0)=2\int_{0}^{x}f(t)f'(t)dt.
$$
In this case, the limits $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}f^{2}(x)=L_{\pm}$ must be $0$ because, otherwise, $f$ would remain bounded away from $0$ for large positive or negative $x$, which would contradict $f \in L^{2}$.

With that in mind, if you assume $f,f'\in L^{2}$, then the following converges in $L^{2}$:
\begin{align}
 \widehat{f'}(s)
    & = \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}f'(x)e^{-ixs}dx \\
    & = \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[\left.f(x)e^{-isx}\right|_{-R}^{R}+is\int_{-R}^{R}f(x)e^{-isx}dx\right] \\
    & = \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{is}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}f(x)e^{-isx}dx \\
    & = is\widehat{f}(s).
\end{align}
So assuming $f,f'\in L^{2}$ is enough to justify the above, assuming that $f$ is locally the integral of $f'$, which is to say that $f$ is locally absolutely continuous, which is equivalent to $f'$ being the weak derivative of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with your context, but I may be able to help out understand the definition and implications on $\lim_{x \rightarrow \pm \infty} f(x)$.

A function is square integrable on $(-\infty, \infty)$, hence the name, if

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)^{\color{red}{2}} \mathrm{d}x \lt \infty
$$

(… and the above makes actually sense, ie. $f$ is [measurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function). However this is true for many, many functions, for example for all continuous functions. I do not think that this is the point of your question, so I will not go into the details here.)

In general

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)^2 \mathrm{d}x \lt \infty
\Rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow \pm \infty} f(x) = 0
$$

is wrong – even worse: $f$ does not even need to be bounded. However there are two nice results:

**Result 1:**
If $f$ is [uniformly continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity), one has indeed

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)| \mathrm{d}x \lt \infty
\Rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow \pm \infty} f(x) = 0
$$

One way to show uniform continuity of $f$, is to show that $f'$ is bounded. (Note however, that there are uniformly continuous functions with unbounded $f'$.)

In your case that means of course $f^2$ needs to be uniformly continuous.

**Result 2:**
If you are unable to use result 1, there is also a weaker but more general result: There exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = \infty$ and

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)| \mathrm{d}x \lt \infty
\Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = 0
$$

Of course you can apply this to $f^2$ as well.

Also you get a similar result for $x_n \rightarrow -\infty$.

Comment: Is this why we can make this assumption when deriving the relation for the Fourier transform of a derivative, i.e. $\mathscr{F}[f']=(ik)\mathscr{F}[f]$?

Comment: I don't think that every sequence $x_n \to \infty$ admits a subsequence with $f(x_{n_k}) \to 0$. But what is true is $f(x + n) \to 0$ for almost every $x$. This is usually sufficient to justify partial integrations. E.g. $\int f' \cdot g\, dx = \lim_n \int_{-x_n}^{y_n} f' \cdot g \, dx = \lim_n [f(y_n)g(y_n) - f(-x_n)g(-x_n) - \int_{-x_n}^{y_n} f \cdot g' \, dx = -\int f \cdot g' \, dx$, where we chose $x_n ,y_n\to \infty$ with $f(y_n)g(y_n) \to 0$ and likewise for $-x_n$.

Comment: @Keba          How does uniform continuity guarantee that $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$ if it is square integrable?

Comment: @PhoemueX: You are right, I edited my answer.